# How do control notification message in background

Tags: ios, notifications, push

in active, use didReceiveRemoteNotification method

but, i want

handling push message in background

How to respond to push notification if app in the background

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When ever you tap on Notification as you say didReceiveRemoteNotification will call and you can handle it.